# How can I know if a question belongs on SO if I don't ask it?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I want to ask a question on SO, but think it might not belong there. How can I ask "Does question X belong here?" without asking X (in case it doesn't)?

**Feature suggestion:** Have a "Suggest Question" button, which functions like the "Ask Question", but places the question into a queue (Like "Unanswered" or "Featured"). While in the queue, no answers can be provided, and only someone with enough reputation can "approve" the question, thus making it a regular question (with a current timestamp)

---

My specific question at the moment is as follows. If someone can give me their opinion it would be great:

I am an undergrad in computer science, and as part of our final year we need to do a "project", estimated at about 500 hours a person (we are a couple of students ~1000 hours). It can basically be anything computer related, either computer theory, algorithms, a tool of some sort or an actual practical program, but should involve some sort of new or interesting things (not just "build a library management system"). I am having trouble coming up with ideas, and was wondering if anyone here had any ideas.

Comment: The [FAQ] isn't clear enough?

Comment: Your question is quite clearly off-topic for SO, as named in the SO FAQ I linked..

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, or Stack Exchange in general.  We're not here to generate a "List of X". However, I hope you find a project that you're able to do.

Comment: It's the very definition of "not constructive", as George hints at. It's a free-for-all, bikeshedding, soft question. It doesn't have an objectively correct answer. "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? I think it is a legitimate question for meta, even if it is not for SO.

Comment: @baruch People most likely disagree with your feature request.

Comment: @baruch: see the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq): votes are different on meta, and can represent disagreement with the suggestion in a post rather than a judgment on its quality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every Stack Exchange site has a FAQ, a list of frequently asked questions. Stack Overflow is no exception: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

The Stack Overflow FAQ lists what kind of questions are on-topic. Your question, however, is not.

Your question is asking for open-ended recommendations. It'll only lead to a whole range of opinions, none of which could ever be the one correct answer.